# Bash script to update docker login not functioning correctly

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to script updating of the login keys to the AWS docker ECR on a CoreOS instance.

If I run:

```
docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws ecr get-login
```

I get as output:

```
docker login -u AWS -p CiBwm0YaISJeRtJ ... -e none https://123456789012.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

If I copy and run that, it works perfectly.  If I don't but instead use this form:

```
$(docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws ecr get-login)
```

It fails with an error.

```
/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://123456789012.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

If I try to assign it to a variable, things get weird.

```
var=$(docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws ecr get-login)
echo "'$var' string"
```

Oddly, when I try to quote the string and echo it, the final quote appears in an unexpected place.

```
docker login -u AWS -p CiBwmEwHgYJ ... YIZIAWUDBAEuMisGdv0KB' stringivOyPO+qNJ3zo87RXwWlOW8TnCtGRd6k6tb0Z35xL2IKMO194+1va56lH0am -e none https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

It's quite a long string, is there perhaps some sort of buffer overflow problem here?

How might I get around it?

Comment: no problem, you can rollback it if you don't like.

Comment: I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `aws ecr get-login` before as input to `eval` to accomplish an actual login.  Doing the same on my CoreOS machine with a command like yours fails with a similar problem to yours:

```
$ eval $(docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login)
/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com1.amazonaws.com
: no such host: lookup 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
/ca.crte daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I used good ol' `set -x` to turn on debugging so I could see exactly what commands were being executed:

```
$ docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login
+ docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login
docker login -u AWS -p CiBwm...hb9E= -e none https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

$ eval $(docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login)
++ docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login
+ eval docker login -u AWS -p CiBwm...DES0= -e none $'https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r'
++ docker login -u AWS -p CiBwm...DES0= -e none $'https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r'
/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com1.amazonaws.com
: no such host: lookup 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
/ca.crte daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Wait, what?  The repository URL is being turned into `$'https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r'` when the command is fed into `eval`, which is causing it to be evaluated in a very bizarre manner.  That `\r` seemed like the problem, so I fed the output of the `docker` command into a text file and then opened it in binary mode with Vim to check.  Sure enough, it's a pesky carriage return character.  Removing that character with `sed` did the trick for me:

```
$ eval $(docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login | sed -e 's/^M//')
++ sed -e $'s/\r//'
++ docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment -ti xueshanf/awscli:latest aws --region=us-east-1 ecr get-login
+ eval docker login -u AWS -p CiBwm...88A8= -e none https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
++ docker login -u AWS -p CiBwm...88A8= -e none https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/core/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

Note: to remove the carriage return, you'll need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to correctly insert the `^M` character.

Hope this helps!  =]

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the [Docker image](https://github.com/xueshanf/docker-awscli), not the AWS CLI; this works fine for me on my Mac with a Homebrew-installed version of the AWS CLI, and on a CentOS machine also natively running the CLI.  Seems like something with the Docker image is adding the carriage return, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is inserting the extra carriage return, because you've told it to allocate a a pseudo-tty (with the option `-t`). If you remove the `-ti`, you won't need to use sed.

```
eval $(docker run --rm --env-file=/etc/aws/environment \
    xueshanf/awscli:latest aws ecr get-login)
```